# Unity 2D controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am having problem with detecting ground (jumping seems to cycle in air) - jump lengths are random and sound seems to cycle. Therefore I guess the ground detection doesn't really work. My code is:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class PlayerCtrl : MonoBehaviour
{
    bool facingRight = true;
    public AudioSource jumpSoundEffect;
    private bool grounded;

    void Start()
    { }
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        grounded = Physics2D.IsTouchingLayers(GetComponent<Collider2D>(), LayerMask.GetMask("Ground"));
    }
    void Update()
    {
        Movement();
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * 4f * Time.deltaTime);
            if (facingRight == false)
                Flip();
            facingRight = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector2.left * 4f * Time.deltaTime);
            if (facingRight == true)
                Flip();
            facingRight = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && grounded)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 50f * Time.deltaTime);
            jumpSoundEffect.Play ();
        }
    }
    void Flip()
    {
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
```

Comment: Because 'jump' is a single event that pretty much instantly sets `grounded` to `false`, multiplying by `Time.deltaTime` doesn't make sense, I think your first step should be to try without it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the bool "grounded" is not changing when you press the space key. If you jump, this bool must be false, so it will come back to the ground.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: As a matter of fact, i did. I said the the variable grounded does not change its value, so the answer is to change it, right after it started jumping.

Comment: @GeorgianTanase The fact that you have a question in your answer makes it unclear.  If you meant it as a rhetorical question, I would make it a statement instead.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with his question, it's a total different matter. I just asked him so that i could help him as much as i could.

Comment: You were right - I was missing "grounded = false;" in the jump part. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to keep this as an answer. Just because it has a question in it doesn't mean it doesn't also provide a solution to the problem.

Comment: @gopi Mark my answer if it helped you resolve your problem.

Comment: OK, to me it's an answer, just remove the questions, they're not relevant and only add noise.

Comment: I confirm. It helped to resolve my problém, I've removed the question from Georgian's suggestion.